# NHibernate Relations

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am working with NHibernate and I get this code below:

```
public class User
{
  public User()
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserConfirmation> UserConfirmation { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email;
  }

  public User()
  {
    UserConfirmation = new List<UserConfirmation>();
    }
}

public class UserConfirmation
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual User { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap :      ClassMap<User>
{
  public UserMap()        
  {
  Id(x => x.Id);            
  Map(x => x.Email);           
  HasMany(x => x.UserConfirmation)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
  Table("user");
}
```

}

```
public class UserConfirmationMap : ClassMap<UserConfirmation>
{
    public UserConfirmationMap()
      {
        Id(x => x.Id);            
        References(x => x.User);
        Table("user_confirmation");
    }
}
```

But when I try to query over like this:

```
QueryOver<UserConfirmation>().Where(x => x.User.Email).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
```

Than it says I do not have the property User.Email.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are using x => x.User.Email
this should be done with another alias, which would be user

```
UserConfirmation userConfirmationAlias;
User userAlias;


    QueryOver<UserConfirmation>(() => userConfirmationAlias)
    .joinAlias(() => userConfirmationAlias.User , () => userAlias)
    .Where(() => userAlias.Email).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
```

something like above should do the trick

Comment: Peferct! I just modify to:

QueryOver<UserConfirmation>()
                .JoinQueryOver(x => x.User)                
                .Take(1)
                .SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this.

```
QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.Email).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
```

x should be a user already. If it's not I would use the intellisense to see what type it thinks it is.

Comment: I do not think so, beacause the problem is about do not find the property User.Email.

Comment: What type does Visual Studio think "x" is in the QueryOver<UserConfirmation>()

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
IQueryOver<UserConfirmation,User> qo = _Session.QueryOver<UserConfirmation,User>().Where(x => x.User.Email).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ instead of QueryOver:

```
Query<UserConfirmation>().Where(x => x.User.Email).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
```

BTW, `.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()` is probably not needed. If `Email` is unique, `.SingleOrDefault()` will be enough. Otherwise, you can use `.FirstOrDefault()`